# Abstract Base Class requiring concretions to have minimum class attributes but allowing for extra

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, class-attributes

I have seen a few questions related to my issue but I've still been unable to come up with an adequate approach.

I have the following base and subclass:

```
class Base:
    __attrs__ = {'one', 'two', 'three'}

    def __init__(self, nums: {str} = None):
        if nums:
            self.__attrs__.update(nums)
        self.nums = self.__attrs__


class Child(Base):
    __attrs__ = {'four', 'five', 'six'}

    def __init__(self, nums: {str} = None):
        # self.__attrs__.update(super().__attrs__.copy())  <-----this works when uncommented
        super(Child, self).__init__(nums)


b = Base()
print(b.nums)

c = Child()
print(c.nums)

# The output, as expected.
{'three', 'two', 'one'}
{'four', 'five', 'six'}
```

The child class is obviously overriding the base class' `__attrs__` value during instantiation. What I'm trying to figure out is how I can have the values from the base class' `__attrs__` inherited and *extended* by the subclass—such that the output would be as follows:

```
{'three', 'two', 'one','four', 'five', 'six'}
```

But not necessarily (or likely) in that order. The first line of the subclass' `__init__` copies the parents' attributes to the instance and achieves the end result. However, as I plan on having *lots* of concretions here, I'm trying to wrap my head around a way to do that in the base class somehow.

Comment: Off-topic: You should not be creating your own dunder attributes as that namespace is reserved for the interpreter's use.

Comment: @martineau thanks for the head's up. Link to some educational materials for myself? Would love to know why when using a name that one is sure isn't used by Python. i.e. *not* `__init__` or etc.

Comment: [Authoritative reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers). Whether it's in use at the moment is irrelevant — you'd like it to work in future versions, too, no?

Comment: @martineau 100% and I appreciate that's enough to avoid using custom dunders. I'd love to know if there were other reasons than "the devs might want that one at some point" though.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. It *doesn't matter* why they might eventually want to, but if they ever do, they know they can safely create names for it with leading and trailing `__`s without breaking anyone's code.

Comment: @martineau I get that.  I was curious if there were any *other* outstanding reasons to avoid that—not that one would be needed. Thanks for the insight and reference above as well.

Comment: Well, two downsides I can think of are: 1.) It's misleading to folks who know the language because it *looks* like some system-defined thing. 2.) The name *isn't* mangled like those that only *start* with dunders are which usually require special handling to reference outside the class (see [**Private name mangling**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers)). BTW, I think you should accept @juanpa.arrivillaga's answer.

Comment: @martineau thanks. The `__` start is what I had intended (conceptually) and didn't realize that I was falling subject to poor practice. Thank you for clearing things up!

Comment: Actually leading dunders are usually *not* needed — you probably only need a single underscore here to indicate it's a non-public implementation-detail subject to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for `__init_subclass__` which is a classmethod you can define on a base class that will be called to initialize any subclasses.

```
>>> class Base:
...     attrs = {'one', 'two', 'three'}
...     def __init_subclass__(cls): # cls will be a subclass!
...         cls.attrs.update(super(cls, cls).attrs)
...
>>> class Child(Base):
...     attrs = {'four', 'five'}
...
>>> Child.attrs
{'two', 'four', 'three', 'five', 'one'}
>>> Base.attrs
{'two', 'one', 'three'}
```

Note, in this case, we pass `cls` explicitly as both arguments to `super`. Otherwise, if you use the zero-argument form, `Foo` would be passed as the first argument, and actually need the subclass! This is a special case, you would almost never want to do this in a regular class method (or instance method!).

Note, as usual, `__init_subclass__` is there to help you avoid having to implement a metaclass. You could do this with a metaclass as follows, although it's a bit clunky because you can't assume the parent has an attrs.

```
>>> class AttrsMeta(type):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         try:
...             parent_attrs = super(self, self).attrs
...         except AttributeError: # parent no attrs, base class?
...             return # handle however you like
...         self.attrs.update(parent_attrs) # assume the class always has an attrs defined
...
>>> class Base(metaclass=AttrsMeta):
...     attrs = {'one', 'two', 'three'}
...
>>> class Child(Base):
...     attrs = {'four', 'five'}
...
>>> Child.attrs
{'two', 'four', 'three', 'five', 'one'}
>>> Base.attrs
{'two', 'one', 'three'}
```

Again, notice `super(self, self)`...

If all of this is a little too magical/implicit for your taste, and I might be inclined to agree, you could always define a decorator, I'd go with an API somewhat like this:

```
>>> def attrs(cls):
...     def update_attrs(subclass):
...         subclass.attrs.update(super(subclass, subclass).attrs)
...         return subclass
...     cls.update_attrs = update_attrs
...     return cls
...
>>> @attrs
... class Base:
...     attrs = {'one', 'two', 'three'}
...
>>> @Base.update_attrs
... class Child(Base):
...     attrs = {'four', 'five'}
...
>>> Child.attrs
{'two', 'four', 'three', 'five', 'one'}
>>> Base.attrs
{'two', 'one', 'three'}
```

Comment: @martineau good point, modified the ouput of my repl session to use those names

Comment: Excellent answer—worked like a charm! I agree that the `super(cls, cls).attrs)` is a *bit* "magical" but this isn't for anything large in scale. Personally, I like that approach more so than the decorators (and certainly the meta class). What's your opinion on @CyanoKobalamyne 's approach above?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your base class to add its own attributes:

```
class Base:
    __attrs__ = {'one', 'two', 'three'}

    def __init__(self, nums: {str} = None):
        self.__attrs__.update(Base.__attrs__)  # <-- add this.
        if nums:
            self.__attrs__.update(nums)
        self.nums = self.__attrs__
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this worked well. I'm not sure what the implications of this approach vs. the __init_subclass__ suggested by @juanpa.arrivillaga. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you implement this behavior in `__init_subclass__`, it will be inherited by subclasses, i.e. classes derived from `Child` will have the attributes of `Child` as well as `Base`. The solution I gave applies only to `Base`, so subclasses of `Child` will inherit attributes from `Base`, but not from `Child`.